# Can not run Golang application in 32 bits machine

Tags: windows, go

I build Golang to 32 bits version in 64 bits machine. However, it has a problem, when I build like that, it will take the "kernel32.dll" inside SysWOW64 folder, but when I run in 32 bits machine (Windows 7). It doesn't have the SysWOW64 folder, so its return an error:

`fatal error: kernel32.dll not found`

Here is my go build command:

```
go build -ldflags "-s -w"
```

Here is my go env:

```
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=386
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\name\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\name\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLCHAIN=auto
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.21.1
set GCCGO=gccgo
set GO386=sse2
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=D:\Center\go.mod
set GOWORK=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_FFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-O2 -MT
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m32 -mthreads -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -ffile-prefix-map=C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build581533674=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Comment: `SysWOW64` is the 32-bit System32 on 64-bit Windows. [All accesses to `%windir%\System32` by a 32-bit application will be redirected to `%windir%\SysWOW64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector). So there'll always be kernel32.dll in the search path

Comment: I think that you need to use the 386 version of the compiler for your operative system

Comment: you can find it in the [downloads section (Go official website)](https://go.dev/dl)

Comment: @otaxhu that is not how the Go compiler works. It is able to cross-compile to any target OS - you can build on Windows x86 for Mac Arm64 if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrording to phuclv answer: "`SysWOW64` is the 32-bit System32 on 64-bit Windows. All accesses to **%windir%\System32** by a 32-bit application will be redirected to **%windir%\SysWOW64**."

So I think in your case, you need to build a **32-bit machine** (or virtual machine) then **copy** and **build** your code in there. Of course you will have to **downgrade** some library to match the OS and sometimes it could be challenging.